# New PC Build crashes frequently, sometimes doesn't boot at all

Tags: boot, bios, crash, desktop-computer, computer-building

I've build a computer from entirely new parts, with the exception of the power supply unit. The new system should draw around 510 Watts at maximum performance, while the PUS is rated for 550W.

However, the setup is giving me quite some trouble. Booting works *sometimes*, but it never stays in a stable state very long.

When I get to the Windows 11 setup, the system will work for a while, and then just reset (i.e. shut down and instantly start booting again).  These crashes also happened before I even installed the new drive and used the previous drive and OS install.

Sometimes I won't even get that far, and I never get anything to show up on my monitor. In these cases, the EZ Debug LEDs are permanently lit up for DRAM and flicker for CPU. However, if I take the ram out, put it back in and boot again, it's a coin flip whether it will keep doing that or just go boot.

If I sit in the BIOS config for a long time, these resets never happen. When I just stare at the first screen on the windows setup, but don't interact at all, I haven't yet had one of these resets. It's always only after I start working through the setup process (though sometimes as early as selecting the keyboard layout, the first step).

Memory is inserted according to motherboard instructions, though I did also try other slot arrangements based on some anecdotes from Reddit.

The parts have been selected using PC Part Picker to check for compatibility. [Here's the full build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/LRL7n6), but for posterity if the link goes down:

- Ryzen 9 5950X
- RTX 4070 TI
- A B550M-based Motherboard
- 32GB of DDR4-3600 RAM
- A PCIe4-NVME SSD

I've paid attention to the firmware warning given by PcPartPicker - the BIOS is up-to-date.

I can't figure this out. My suspects are:

- RAM is borked?
- RAM is misconfigured in BIOS. It shows "Adjusted DRAM Frequency" as 2666, but it still recognizes that the sticks do 3600. When I activated XMP, the setup process got a little deeper before crashing, but that might have been a coincidence.
- Motherboard is borked?
- Power Supply is too weak. **Note: The PSU has a few years under the belt and is the only component that hasn't been updated**. This seems unlikely, as no components would really draw a lot of power during windows setup.

Any takes on what I should try next?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many power supplies degrade with time (or have never given the rated power). Note that Windows startup causes a big power draw as all devices get initialized.

Comment: Did you bother to take any kind of esd protection? Momentarily touching metal does not count. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0lsHDU2Sr4 for an indication of the damage you could do.

Comment: I would suspect the power supply.  Does it beep while starting up?

Comment: @Bib Thanks for the note! Yes, I took all precautions you can in a home environment, from grounding to not working on a carpet to high humidity.

Comment: @RohitGupta There aren't any beeps, no.

Comment: @harrymc Since you seem to know more about this, could you maybe point me to some proper sources? I've tried to read up on this over the last couple of days, but everything I can find is pure hearsay and speculation, from "expect rated capacity to drop by 10% each year" to "Every PSU can _technically_ handle more than rated capacity, but it will initiate shutdown past capacity. Therefore, degradation doesn't really affect capacity, it only affects efficiency"...

Comment: ... I'll still buy a new one and see if it helps, but I find it had to believe that selecting a keyboard layout in the windows installation draws more total power than rendering 3D-Video or playing fancy games did with the previous hardware, where this has never been an issue.

Comment: Okay, so you used an esd wriststrap & used an antistatic mat which you connected both to ground?

Comment: @Bib Yes, I and the work surface were consistently connected to a common ground.